# Dependency Injection: Creating object factories vs. using inversion of control containers

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, asp.net-core

When requiring to use dependency injection, I always use IoC containers such as Ninject, Unity, or the built-in one in ASP.Net Core MVC. However, I've just come across the idea of "why not creating an object factory" and then instead of intercepting calls to parameterized constructors (via IoC containers), retrieve those objects from the factory in a parameterless constructor. For instance:

```
Dictionary<Type, Func<Object>> TransientFactory;
Dictionary<Type, Object> SingletonFactory;
```

In my opinion, this technique would speed up the whole thing, but I'm not sure to what extent that would be true and that is the point of the question. Considering the fact that the life-cycle of the object can be easily controlled in consuming context, what possible advantages can an IoC container provide in this case?

Comment: By speed up, do you mean "make it faster to develop" or "make it run faster"?

Comment: @joshp: It makes it slower to develope (more coding needed) but faster to run.

Comment: please don't **[cross-post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/cross-posting/info "'Cross-posting is frowned upon...'")**: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47849411/dependency-injection-creating-object-factories-vs-using-inversion-of-control-c "Cross-posting is frowned upon as it leads to fragmented answers splattered all over the network..."

Comment: @gnat: You are right, I'm new to this SO community, other post will be deleted.

Comment: It's not practical to ask whether IOC makes code run faster or slower without talking about specific cases with specific libraries. Often the difference is insignificant. As for making it slower or faster to develop that depends greatly on how to the IOC container is used and how well it fits the team's skills. Some teams lose a lot of time on confusion and troubleshooting hell with IOC. Others see it as a boost to productivity.

Comment: @joshp: The thing is, why outsourcing the performance (to IoC containers) while we can optimize it using customized factories? What is that special advantage that IoC containers provide?

Comment: If you're looking for performance optimization, DryIoC is about as fast as it gets (in some cases, it's faster than the `new` keyword).  Most of the cost of IoC containers is in expression tree evaluation, which can be greatly sped up by expression compilation.  DryIoC takes it a step further by using its own custom expression compiler.  See https://github.com/dadhi/FastExpressionCompiler

Comment: @RobertHarvey: That's right but you know that there are frameworks which DryIoC does not support and the same for many other containers. For example, I also do Spring MVC where the built-in IoC is pretty silly and works totally differently. My question is rather general and I'm not looking for a very fast framework.

Comment: I think your question is almost impossible to understand without a real example. Can you show some snippet which contrasts the resulting differences in code between an IoC approach and your approach?

Comment: A benefit of IoC containers is that you define individual interface implementations and then, in a perfect world, never have to call your objects' constructors. The container composes the entire object graph for you. If you use a factory then what happens when one class has dependencies and each of those classes have dependencies, and so on?  I don't want to manage that with factories. I want my container to resolve an `ISomething` and resolve its dependencies, and their dependencies, and so on.